# JavaScript/AJAX prints weirdly

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

My JavaScript/AJAX prints comments. It's all good, until I want to insert/get more than one comment. It duplicates itself. This feels like a nesting/missed parenthesis problem in my code, but I can't be able to find it...

My JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = 'comment-get.inc.php';

    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(index, item) {
        var t = '';
        t += '<div class="comment_holder" id="_'+item.id+'">';
        t += '<div class="user"> <img src="src/img/page3_img7.jpg" alt="" class="img_inner fleft">';
        t += '<div class="extra_wrapper">';
        t += ''+item.username+'<br>';
        t += ''+item.date+'<br>';
        t += '<button class="button2" type="button" id="'+item.id+'">Delete</button>';
        t += '</div></div>';
        t += ''+item.message+'<br><br>';
        t += '</div>';
        $('.comment_holder').prepend(t);
        add_delete_handlers();
        });
    });

    add_delete_handlers();

    $('#postButton').click(function(){
        comment_post_btn_click();
});

function comment_post_btn_click()
{
    //text in textarea with username, page and date
    var _username = $('#postUsername').val();
    var _page = $('#postPage').val();
    var _date = $('#postDate').val();
    var _message = $('#postMessage').val();

    if(_message.length > 0)
        {
            //proceed with ajax callback
            $('#postMessage').css('border', '1px solid #ABABAB');
            $.post("comment-set.inc.php",
                {
                    task : "comment-set",
                    username : _username,
                    page : _page,
                    date : _date,
                    message : _message
                }
                ).success(
                    function(data)
                    {
                        //Task: Insert html into the div
                        comment_set(jQuery.parseJSON(data));
                        console.log("ResponseText: " + data);
                    });
        }
    else
        {
            //text in area is empty
            $('#postMessage').css('border', '1px solid #FF0000');
            console.log("Comment is empty");
        }
    //remove text after posting
    $('#postMessage').val("");
}

function add_delete_handlers()
{
    $('.button2').each(function()
    {
        var btn = this;
        $(btn).click(function()
        {
            comment_delete(btn.id);
        });
    });
}

function comment_delete(_id)
{
    $.post("comment-del.inc.php",
        {
            task : "comment-del",
            id : _id
        }
        ).success( 
            function(data)
            {
                $('#_' + _id).detach();
            });
}

function comment_set(data)
{
    var t = '';
    t += '<div class="comment_holder" id="_'+data.comment.id+'">';
    t += '<div class="user"> <img src="src/img/page3_img7.jpg" alt="" class="img_inner fleft">';
    t += '<div class="extra_wrapper">';
    t += ''+data.comment.username+'<br>';
    t += ''+data.comment.date+'<br>';
    t += '<button class="button2" type="button" id="'+data.comment.id+'">Delete</button>';
    t += '</div></div>';
    t += ''+data.comment.message+'<br><br>';
    t += '</div>';

    $('.comment_holder').prepend(t);
    add_delete_handlers();
}
});
```

Comments.php:

```
<?php

class Comments {

    public function set($message, $username, $date, $page) {
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'trdb');
        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('', '$username', '$page', '$date', '$message')";
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if($query){ 
            $std = new stdClass();
            $std->id = mysqli_insert_id($connect);
            $std->message = $message;
            $std->username = $username;
            $std->date = $date;
            $std->page = $page;

            return $std;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public function del($id) {
        $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'trdb');
        $sql = "DELETE FROM comments WHERE id = $id";
        $query = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

        if($query)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment-get.inc.php:

```
<?php
$page = htmlentities("/index.php?page=maplepancakes", ENT_QUOTES);

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'trdb');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE page='$page' ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = $connect->query($sql);
$data = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_data = array(
    'id' => $row['id'],
    'username' => $row['username'],
    'date' => $row['date'],
    'message' => $row['message']
    );
    array_push($data, $row_data);
    }
?>

<?php
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

Comment-set.inc.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['task']) && $_POST['task'] == 'comment-set'){
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $date = $_POST['date'];
    $page = $_POST['page'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

    require_once 'comments.php';

    if(class_exists('Comments')){
        $userInfo = $username;
        $commentInfo = Comments::set($message, $username, $date, $page);

        $std = new stdClass();
        $std->user = $userInfo;
        $std->comment = $commentInfo;
        echo json_encode($std);
    }
}
?>
```

Picture of the problem (json_encode in the bottom of the picture containing 3 comments):

[image]

Comment: You might need to show the relevant parts of your PHP or HTML scripts.  It's hard to put _it all_ together without it.

Comment: I added the rest of the related code.

Comment: there is a problem you'd prepend div has `.comment_holder` class to same class `.comment_holder` !

Comment: Thank you! I made a second <div> element in the HTML and messed around with the JS part. It now works!

Comment: Yes, you got it glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your comments div container has class `.comment_holder` so each time with new comment you prepend to all class's so create comment container with unique id an prepend to this. like this `$('#comment_container').prepend(t);` this with work.